# Kylo plugin for UI is not working

Tags: angularjs, plugins, kylo

I would like to extend Kylo user interface. From documentation, i understood that I can use Plugin mechanism to add new features and I am referring to the examples [available here](https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/tree/master/samples/plugins/example-module).

I have built this example code and deployed the generated jar files to /opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin folder and restarted the kylo-services.

But I am dont see any changes in the UI. As per my understanding, there should be a new group in left hand navigation pane but there are no UI level changes in the kylo UI.

I am using dladmin userid and logs (kylo-ui and kylo-services) really did not indicate any error.

Where can I see if the plugin is really picked up by kylo? Which logs tell me what is going on with this plugin? Any suggestions will be of great help.

Thanks
Gana

Comment: One thing to check is file permissions, the plugin jar should be readable by kylo user

Comment: @Ruslans: Thanks for your reply. I have taken care of that. I just realized that I have deployed the kylo-ui plugin also into kylo-services/plugin folder instead of kylo-ui/plugin folder. After making this change, i am able to see UI changes. Silly mistake, took few hours of time. Anyhow thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hello, did the new "accessExample" permission work for you? I cant seem to be able to assign it to a group, when I check it and hit save it goes back to being unchecked..

Answer (score 1):

*The mistake i did is copying kylo UI into /opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin folder.*

**The generated jar files should go into different plugin folders.**

Kylo Services plugin should be copied to /opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin folder.
Kylo UI plugin should be copied to /opt/kylo/kylo-ui/plugin folder.

service kylo-services restart
service kylo-ui restart

And its my bad that i mistakenly copied kylo-ui plugin into kylo-services folder. After I copied into correct folders and service restart, I am able to find the UI changes.

Thanks for your attention.